# MongoDB and Spring MVC: PATCH operation?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, patch

I have the following simple `Java` Controller with the `Spring Web` framework:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rounds")
@Slf4j
public class RoundController {

    private RoundService roundService;

    @Autowired
    public RoundController(RoundService roundService) {
        this.roundService = roundService;
    }

    @GetMapping(
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Round> find() {

        return roundService.find();
    }

    @GetMapping(
        path = "/{userId}",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Round> get(@PathVariable String userId) {

        return roundService.getRoundsByUserId(userId);
    }

    @PostMapping(
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Round create(@Valid @NotNull @RequestBody Round round) {

        roundService.create(round);

        return round;
    }

    @DeleteMapping(
        path = "/{id}",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void delete(@PathVariable String id) {

        ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(id);

        roundService.delete(objectId);
    }
}
```

When using `Mongo` is there a best practice for doing an update / patch for an object?

Is it best to just use the `POST` method, and re-save the Round object in the DB with the changes the user has made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, the best practice should not be the use of the POST for doing an update/patch.

Keep you POST to do only Round creation.

If you use spring data mongodb just call the save method of your repository with your entity
see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html

For an Update, better to add PUT /{roundId} in your controller and either :

- call your save method if you have all the Round data
- call a findById to have the full data and set the data you want to change, then save (but this is more like a PATCH)

Or you can also add a PATCH /{roundId} and update just the field you want in your document
see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html